# system file, read write o create custom metadata or attributes extended

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems

:

I am looking for a way to read, write or create (custom) tags, extended attributes or metadata from any file. Without libraries and language c or c + +. I think I can be with fopen, fread, fwrite, but not how to access the metadata.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific about the metadata or attributes you are talking about? Do you refer to metadata that you are creating and storing? Or metadata that the operating system is managing? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I mean I'm creating and storing metadata. My SO is Linux.

Comment: So, you just need to create the file that will hold the metadata, and write to that file. Can you show us what you have tried to do, and where you got stuck?

Comment: No, I'm looking for read write any existing file, do not want to create a file specifically for storing metadata. Similarly as done in the extended attributes but custom. Thanks @Rob

Answer (score 4):

The Linux system calls for manipulating extended attributes are `setxattr`, `getxattr`, and `remotexattr`. This program might do what you are asking for:

```
// UNTESTED
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main () {
  const char* file = "/work/a.txt";
  const char* attr = "user.MyAttr";
  const char* value = "MyValue";
  int rc = setxattr(file, attr, value, strlen(value), 0);
  if(rc < 0)
    perror(file);
  return !!rc;
}
```

Comment: Attribute name *may* have to prefixed by `"user."`, I'm not sure.

Comment: If Rob is working, the prefix "user" is mandatory. I'm doing this project in my spare time. **Thanks** Rob. Then I tell you about.

Comment: I have also tested getfattr and setfattr in the command line, is fantastic. The question is whether this could be "crossplatform" or I have to do for each?